# Add jsonserde.jar to EMR Hive permanantly

Tags: hive, emr

We know that

```
add jar s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/jsonserde.jar;
```

is only effective during the current session.

Is there a way to add jar to Hive permanently and globally so that the jar will be available during the lifecycle of the cluster?

**UPDATE**:
I figured out a way: download the jar by using aws cli, `aws s3 cp s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/jsonserde.jar .`, then copy the jar to `/usr/lib/hive/lib` of all nodes of the EMR cluster

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

insert your ADD JAR commands in your .hiverc file and start hive.

```
 add jar yourjarName.jar
```

1. **What is .hiverc file?**

It is a file that is executed when you launch the hive shell - making it an ideal place for adding any hive configuration/customization you want set, on start of the hive shell. This could be:

- Setting column headers to be visible in query results
- Making the current database name part of the hive prompt
- Adding any jars or files
- Registering UDFs

2 **.hiverc file location**

- The file is loaded from the hive conf directory.
- I have the CDH4.2 distribution and the location is:
  /etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive1
- If the file does not exist, you can create it. It needs to be
  deployed    to every node from where you might launch the Hive shell.

ref-http://hadooped.blogspot.in/2013/08/hive-hiverc-file.html

Comment: But sometimes I don't use Hive shell, I use Hue, then .hiverc won't get executed

Comment: Would also be interested in a solution for Hue